# How to iterate pages and get the link and title of each news article

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm scraping the 10 pages from this site https://nypost.com/search/China+COVID-19/page/1/?orderby=relevance (and its following pages)

I expect in total 100 links and titles should be stored in **pagelinks**.
However, only 10 links and 10 titles had been saved.

How could I scrape the 10 pages and store the article links/titles?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
def scrape(url):
    user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
    request = 0
    urls = [f"{url}{x}" for x in range(1,11)]
    params = {
       "orderby": "relevance",
    }
    for page in urls:
        response = requests.get(url=page,
                                headers=user_agent,
                                params=params) 
        # controlling the crawl-rate
        start_time = time() 
        #pause the loop
        sleep(randint(8,15))
        #monitor the requests
        request += 1
        elapsed_time = time() - start_time
        print('Request:{}; Frequency: {} request/s'.format(request, request/elapsed_time))
        clear_output(wait = True)
    
        #throw a warning for non-200 status codes
        if response.status_code != 200:
            warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(request, response.status_code))

        #Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
        if request > 72:
            warn('Number of request was greater than expected.')
            break
        
        
        #parse the content
        soup_page = bs(response.text) 
        #select all the articles for a single page
        containers = soup_page.findAll("li", {'class': 'article'})
        
        #scrape the links of the articles
        pagelinks = []
        for link in containers:
            url = link.find('a')
            pagelinks.append(url.get('href'))
        
    print(pagelinks)


        #scrape the titles of the articles
        title = []
        for link in containers:
            atitle = link.find(class_ = 'entry-heading').find('a')
            thetitle = atitle.get_text()
            title.append(thetitle)

    print(title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `pagelinks = []` out of `for page in urls:`.
By putting it inside the `for page in urls:` loop you are overwriting pagelinks list on each iteration of a page so, in the end, you are getting only 10 links from the last page only.

```
def scrape(url):
    user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
    request = 0
    urls = [f"{url}{x}" for x in range(1,11)]
    params = {
       "orderby": "relevance",
    }
    pagelinks = []
    title = []
    for page in urls:
        response = requests.get(url=page,
                                headers=user_agent,
                                params=params) 
        # controlling the crawl-rate
        start_time = time() 
        #pause the loop
        sleep(randint(8,15))
        #monitor the requests
        request += 1
        elapsed_time = time() - start_time
        print('Request:{}; Frequency: {} request/s'.format(request, request/elapsed_time))
        clear_output(wait = True)

        #throw a warning for non-200 status codes
        if response.status_code != 200:
            warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(request, response.status_code))

        #Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
        if request > 72:
            warn('Number of request was greater than expected.')
            break


        #parse the content
        soup_page = bs(response.text) 
        #select all the articles for a single page
        containers = soup_page.findAll("li", {'class': 'article'})

        #scape the links of the articles
        
        for link in containers:
            url = link.find('a')
            pagelinks.append(url.get('href'))

        for link in containers:
            atitle = link.find(class_ = 'entry-heading').find('a')
            thetitle = atitle.get_text()
            title.append(thetitle)
    print(title)
    print(pagelinks)
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it as you said, but still, only 10 links were stored.

Comment: Change the line bs(response.text, 'lxml') to bs(response.text) and that should work I've recived 100 links.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks a lot! I tried to scrape the 100 titles as well, but I only get 10. Could you please help me with that as well? The code I added is : 
       `title = []
        for link in containers:    
        #scrape the titles of the articles
            atitle = link.find(class_ = 'entry-heading').find('a')
            thetitle = atitle.get_text()
            title.append(thetitle)
    print(title)`

Comment: You welcome, please mark the answer and vote up. Try to put the title outside the for loop as well.

Comment: How could I mark the answer? I already voted up for it.
Could you maybe revise your post to include the code for scraping the titles? I tried to put print(title) outside for loop, but it doesn´t work. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit the title part in your code that I will be able to see it. To mark the answer you have a v near the answer just click it.

Comment: I edited the code, please help me to scrape the 100 titles. thanks a lot!
I marked your answer as well. :)

Comment: I edited the code with the title part just note that it is the same as pagelinks when you initiate a list that needs to aggregate all the results put outside the loop because in the loop it's getting initiation on every iteration.